# Django Store with limited options

Tags: django, paypal, payment-gateway, satchmo

I want to have a pricing screen with only 4 options avaliable for the user to choose from. After this I need some integration to paypal to recieve the payments. Is it best to use satchmo for something this simple or is there another option available?

Answer (score 0):

you could easily roll your own site if you have only 4 different items and a paypal integration.  Paypal makes it super easy to integrate.

What happens if you want offer 5 products down the line? or a differnt line of products? If so it might be the stronger move to go with satchmo.

Comment: Hmm that's true. I recently just found this https://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal I think I'll be using this for now. Thoughts?

Comment: It all depends on what you need, paypal offers very simple integration.  If a user will just buy one product you can just use paypal directly https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_paypal_shopping_cart, they have a shopping cart option too